# Compound function: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I've run into this familiar error (TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable) in my code, but can't figure out how to fix it. I'm trying to add up the value of everything in the market, so I set up a loop that multiplies 1 banana by $4, then subtracts a banana from the stock, moves onto the next item, and skips items that have zero stock left. I want it to continue until all items stock are zero, essentially adding up the value of all items in the market. The compute_total_value function is the one that SHOULD do this, but the error pops up. **Here is the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/untitled2/shopping.py", line 62, in <module>
    total_market_value = compute_total_value(market_items)
  File "/Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/untitled2/shopping.py", line 49, in compute_total_value
    while sum(stock[items]) != 0:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code:

```
# Here is the market
stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}


def compute_total_value(food):
    total = 0
    for items in food:
        while sum(stock[items]) != 0:       #error is on this line
            if stock[items] != 0:
                total += prices[items]
                stock[items] -= 1
            else:
                continue
        if sum(stock[items]) == 0:
            break
    return total

market_items = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "pear"]

total_market_value = compute_total_value(market_items)

print (total_market_value)
```

Comment: Please edit this to give a correctly-formatted [mcve].

Comment: @tony-barbarino Please don't add phrases like "Thanks for your help!" when editing. Editors should normally _remove_ fluff phrases like that.

Comment: your logic make little sense to my, you want the value of the current market list, that is 8.5, or you want the value of everything in the stock, that is 81.5??

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is very simple. The function `sum()` requires an iterable element to work; but you have `stock[items]`... `stock` is a dictionary and `items` is a string key; for example `stock['banana']` whose value is `6` that is an integer and not is a iterable.

One possible solution is: `sum(stock.values())`, since `stock.values()` returns a list of all values in the dictionary.

But, for your goal it is not necessary to use the function `sum`.

In your code, the solution can be:

```
stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}


def compute_total_value(food):
    total = 0
    for items in food:
        while stock[items] != 0:
            total += prices[items]
            stock[items] -= 1
    return total

market_items = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "pear"]

total_market_value = compute_total_value(market_items)

print (total_market_value)
```